# Can Arduino accept HDMI input video stream, and output it without any modification to the video?

Tags: input, stream

I'd like to know please whether an Arduino can accept an HDMI signal from a satellite receiver, let it flow without any modification to the stream, and output it to TV?

Comment: what do you want to do that wire doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

No.

HDMI uses multiple serial data streams at gigabit rates. No Arduino is ever going to do that sort of thing.  If you want something programmable to do that kind of thing you need an FPGA.